# Nested case conditionals in PostgreSQL, syntax error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL and I would like to combine these two case conditions, but when I uncomment the code, I get a syntax error. This is not a difficult instruction. I want to divide or multiply the obtained number depending on the condition. How can I enter it so that the code is compiled?

```
SELECT
SUM(

CASE
    WHEN transactions.recipient_account_bill_id = recipientBill.id AND recipientBill.user_id = 2
    THEN 1
    ELSE -1
END * transactions.amount_money

/* CASE
    WHEN senderBillCurrency.id = recipientBillCurrency.id
    THEN NULL
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN recipientBillCurrency.base = true
            THEN /
            ELSE *
        END senderBillCurrency.current_exchange_rate
END */

) as TOTAL

FROM transactions

LEFT JOIN bills AS senderBill ON senderBill.id = transactions.sender_account_bill_id
LEFT JOIN bills AS recipientBill ON recipientBill.id = transactions.recipient_account_bill_id
LEFT JOIN currency as senderBillCurrency ON senderBillCurrency.id = senderBill.currency_id
LEFT JOIN currency as recipientBillCurrency ON recipientBillCurrency.id = recipientBill.currency_id

WHERE 2 IN (senderBill.id, recipientBill.id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create dynamic SQL expressions like that. A `CASE` expression cannot return an operator as if SQL was some sort of macro language. You can only return an expression.

You already used the following approach using `1` and `-1` with your multiplication. Why not also use it with `N` and `1/N`:

```sql
<some expression> * CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 / N ELSE N END
```

Or in your case:

```sql
<some expression> * CASE
    WHEN senderBillCurrency.id = recipientBillCurrency.id THEN 1
    WHEN recipientBillCurrency.base THEN 1 / senderBillCurrency.current_exchange_rate
    ELSE senderBillCurrency.current_exchange_rate
END
```

Notice, you can put several `WHEN` clauses in a `CASE` expression. No need to nest them